# Is there a way to use NavigationLink() on SwiftUI to go to a random view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to use the NavigationLink() Button to go to one of four views, and I want it to be random.

I tried to use a random variable and the switch function, but it turns out that I cannot modify the variable inside the NavigationLink() button (it gives me this error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View') like I would in a normal button. This is what I got:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State var valore = Int.random(in: 1...4)

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        NavigationLink {
            switch valore {
            case 1:
                ContentView1()
            case 2:
                ContentView2()
            case 3:
                ContentView3()
            case 4:
                ContentView4()
            default:
                ContentView()
            }
            } label: {
                Image("Retro")
                    .resizable()
                    .cornerRadius(27.0)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .padding()
            }
        Text("\(valore)")
            .bold()
            .font(.title)
    }
}
```

}
I would like to "re-randomize" the variable 'valore' inside each case so that when it goes back the number has changed, and so the view that it will go to next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of Property Wrappers.

On your ContentView1...4, declare a Binding var on each one like this below:

```
@Binding var valore: Int
```

Inside each ContentView1...4 add a `.onAppear` and update the value there:

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    @Binding var valore: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Content 1")
        }
        .onAppear {
            valore = Int.random(in: 1...4)
        }
    }
}
```

This will automatically change the *valore* value.

Your ContentView should look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var valore = Int.random(in: 1...4)

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        NavigationLink {
            switch valore {
            case 1:
                ContentView1(valore: $valore)
            case 2:
                ContentView2(valore: $valore)
            case 3:
                ContentView3(valore: $valore)
            case 4:
                ContentView4(valore: $valore)
            default:
                ContentView1(valore: $valore)
            }
        } label: {
            Image("Retro")
                .resizable()
                .cornerRadius(27.0)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding()
        }
        Text("\(valore)")
            .bold()
            .font(.title)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you very much!